# I'm working on a web app involving firebase firestore, and I want to query just 1 specific field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, materialize

I'm building a web app that involves using firebase firestore to keep track of users. I am also using firebase authentication on this web app. I have a collection of users and a document for each user. Currently, I am still testing this so I am the only user. One of the fields is account type. It is either standard or admin. I want only admins to be able to sign in. I am trying to do this by finding the document associated with that user and seeing if the account type is admin. Here is my code.

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        if (//Add Code Here) {
            setupUI(user);
        }  else {
            auth.signOut;
        };
       } else {
        setupUI();
    };
```

I have already tried this:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        if (db.collection('users').get(auth.currentUser.uid).type == 'admin') {
            setupUI(user);
        }  else {
            auth.signOut;
        };
       } else {
        setupUI();
    };
```

It didn't work. I have watched so many youtube videos and looked at so many web pages, trying to figure it out, but I have seen nothing useful to me. I am fairly new to firebase auth, so I have no idea what to do. I looked at the firebase docs, but they confused me too. I am also pretty new to javascript.

Edit #1:
I edited my code so that the program will work properly. Now, when I open the page, the console shows this: subscribe.ts:239 ReferenceError: accountType is not defined
at Object.next (auth.js:7).
I think this is because I create that constant inside the function and then try to reference it outside the function. How do I create a variable inside a function that I can reference outside a function?
I now have this code:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser.uid);
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            const accountType = doc.data().type;
        });
        if (accountType == 'admin') {
            setupUI(user);
        }  else {
            auth.signOut;
        };
       } else {
        setupUI();
    };
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have now?  If something is not working the way you expect, please edit the question to be clear about that.  Include only the relevant code, not everything you use the render the app. I suggest reading this to help with asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your response. In auth.js line 3, there is a spot that says "add code here". That is where it will find out what that field says for just that one document. I don't know what to add there.

Comment: There is way too much code here.  I suggest editing down the question to draw focus to the one thing you're having problems with.  Your code should show an attempt at solving the problem, describing what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I have removed a lot of it and added what I have already tried, and what I need help with.

Comment: What you're trying to do here is kind of far off the mark.  `get()` returns a promise, and you need to use that to get a hold of the contents of the document.  You can't read just one field - you have to read the entire document and pick the fields out of it that you want to use.  I suggest reviewing the documentation about that.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you are saying. The link that you provided me was very helpful. I was able to figure out what code to add and I did. I now have an error message in the console. I have posted an edit with my new code and the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225301/discussion-between-anonoymous-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: You're going through a lot of problems here in quick succession, for which Stack Overflow is not an ideal place. Your latest problems has to do with: 1) the fact that you declare the const inside the function, so it can only be access there, 2) the asynchronous nature of cloud APIs. I recommend reading up on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous and

Comment: I understand that I can't access the constant because I declared it inside the function. I would like to know if there is any other way to store data for a short time that can be accessed outside of the function. And, I am looking into the Asynchronous code URL that you sent me. I think that will be helpful.